# Django: Generating multiple similar tables and link them with another table

Tags: python-3.x, django, database, django-models, database-design

I want to store the historical stock price data in a database.

E.g. I want a table which will contain the historical data of AAPL stock. In this table I'll have columns like date, open_price, close_price, etc. and this table will be linked to another table which will hold the fundamental information of the stock.

Now, I want to do this for multiple stocks. As there are thousands of stocks, it'll be a very time consuming process to create a model for each stock.

So, I want something like the following:

```
class StockData(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    open_price = models.DecimalField()
    close_price = models.DecimalField()
    high_price = models.DecimalField()
    low_price = models.DecimalField()
    adj_close_price = models.DecimalField()
    volume = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    

class StockInfo(models.Model):
    stock_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    # other fundamental information
    
    # How to do this: link the instance of StockData here, which will hold the data of particular stock with name 'stock_name'
```

How should I go about doing this in django?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [database normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php) it is not specific to a language or framework. Instead of thinking about how django can solve this problem, think of how your design can be implemented in django.

Comment: Maybe I could not frame the question properly. I was looking for [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

Thank you for your response!